# How to extract data as raster from binary file

Tags: r, binary, binaryfiles, grib, ncdf4

I have the binary file and its control file is provided in figure [Control File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq9Ja.jpg). I want to extract the rain with latitude and longitude as raster in r. Can anybody help?

```
    library(weathercan)
    library(rNOMADS)
    library(rgdal)
    library(raster)
    library(ncdf4)
    library(fields)
    library(sp)
    library(sf)
    library(gdalUtilities)
    library(rgdal)      
    library(tiff)
    library(ncdf4)
    library(gdalUtils)
    library(maps)
    library(maptools)
    library(ncdf.tools)
    library(ncdfgeom)
    library(rgl)
    library(rlas)
    library(AnnotationDbi)
    library(SDMTools)

    zz <- file("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20090101.RT", "rb")
    zz
    summary(zz)
```

The output is given as

```
zz <-file("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20090101", "rb")
zz
A connection with                                                                                       
description "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20090101"
class       "file"                                                                     
mode        "rb"                                                                       
text        "binary"                                                                   
opened      "opened"                                                                   
can read    "yes"                                                                      
can write   "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [gdal](https://gdal.org). There is a wrapper recently published https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils/gdalUtils.pdf